# App crashes picking image from external storage

Tags: java, android-studio

My onActivityResult code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GalleryPick && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!= null) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        CropImage.activity()
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                .start(SettingsActivity.this);
    }

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
        }
    }
}
```

when I try to pick image from device gallery it crashes at Image crop activity
tell me what is the issue with my code

**And the error says**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/25/ORIGINAL/NONE/1270245750 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F25/ORIGINAL/NONE/1270245750} }} to activity {com.gihan.mechat/com.gihan.mechat.SettingsActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.gihan.mechat/com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

**And app crash exactly at**

```
start(SettingsActivity.this);
```

`

Comment: Make sure you use FileProvider and add the code for that in Manifest

Answer (score 1):

Check for permission, I had this type of issue once,
For API > 29 we need this code below in the   in the manifest file.

```
android: requestLegacyExternalStorage = true
```

This code is necessary for getting storage permission.
Also, go to permission manager in setting in your phone and check the toggle button there.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you why it's happening `have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` Have you?